# Why does my carpet have so many holes?

Tags: fractals

I always liked the Sierpinski triangle, and happened upon the related article about the [Sierpinski carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet).

The article is pretty sparse, and states the area of the carpet is zero (in standard Lebesgue measure).

Is there a proper proof or book in which a proof may be found?

Comment: Lebesgue measure can be caluclated by subtracting measures of intevals $(1/3, 2/3)$ , $(1/9, 2/9)$ , $(7/9, 8/9)$ etc from measure of interval $(0,1)$. So if you want to calculate measure of carpet you should subtract measures of $(1/3,2/3)\times(1/3,2/3)$, $(1/9, 2/9)\times(1/9,2/9)$, $(1/9, 2/9)\times(7/9,8/9)$, $(7/9, 8/9)\times(1/9,2/9)$, $(7/9, 8/9)\times(7/9,8/9)$ etc from measure of $(0,1)\times(0,1)$

Comment: Think about how much area you're removing at each stage of the carpet's construction, and see what all those areas summed up converge to. (In short, prove this: the area that remains after $n$ steps of the carpet's construction is $\left(\dfrac89\right)^n$. What does this converge to as $n\to \infty$?)

Comment: You should look into Hausdorff measure and dimension. The Hausdorff dimension of the carpet is higher than 1 and less than 2. So the area is 0 and the length is infinite.

Answer (score 5):

If after $n$ iterations for the square the area of the carpet is $A_n$, then you have the recursion $A_{n+1}=\dfrac{8}{9} A_n$, so $A_{n}=\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n A_0$ and the limit of the area is $0$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty simple. Thanks.

Comment: @Muencher, if you feel that Henry's answer is satisfactory, please click on the check mark on the left of Henry's answer.